# docker-compose run throws error: Failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)

Tags: docker, apple-m1

While trying to run a docker container using `docker-compose run` I encountered an error:

`runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22) fatal error: newosproc`

I have a mac with M1.

I have tried to update (and failed to resolve) the docker file using ([source](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)):

`FROM --platform=linux/amd64 your_amd64_image`

I also tried deleting my docker containers and rebuilding as well as updating `docker desktop`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me that I didn't see posted anywhere on the internet was:

Check `docker-compose.yml` for `command` and change `service` parameter name to `entrypoint`:

```
terminal:
  volumes:
    - ".:/app"
  extends:
    file: docker-compose.yml
    service: base
  command: sh #should be entrypoint
```

Change to:

```
terminal:
  volumes:
    - ".:/app"
  extends:
    file: docker-compose.yml
    entrypoint: base
  command: sh #should be entrypoint
```

Comment: Whether one or the other of these works is incredibly dependent on the underlying image, and doesn't have any obvious relation to whether the main container process can create threads.  For typical use you shouldn't need either `command:` or `entrypoint:` in your Compose file.